# How to append a carriage return to replacement text in osx bash script

Tags: macos, bash, script, sed, newlines

I've tried numerous answers that I searched for here, and for some reason nothing is working

I have a bash script which I'd like to use to process a series of files.

Here's a simplified example

a sql file:  **foo.bar.users.sql**:

```
-- mysql script
```

a bash script **foo.sh** which wants to insert a "use" statement at the top of the sql file

```
db=$1
cat foo.bar.users.sql  | sed "1s/^/use $db;\'$'\n/" > tmp.txt; mv tmp.txt foo.bar.users.sql
```

running **foo.sh** this way

```
foo.sh foo
```

My desired goal is for **foo.bar.users.sql** to wind up like this:

```
use foo;
-- mysql script
```

I've tried so many variations of advice found so far, nothing works, here is what I've tried and what it does

script:

```
db=$1
cat foo.bar.users.sql  | sed "1s/^/use $db;\'$'\n/" > tmp.txt; mv tmp.txt foo.bar.users.sql
```

result:

```
use foo;'$'n-- mysql script
```

script:

```
db=$1
cat foo.bar.users.sql  | sed "1s/^/use $db;\\$'\n'/" > tmp.txt; mv tmp.txt foo.bar.users.sql
```

result

```
use foo;$'n'-- mysql script
```

script:

```
db=$1
cat foo.bar.users.sql  | sed "1s/^/use $db;\\$'\\n'/" > tmp.txt; mv tmp.txt foo.bar.users.sql
```

result

```
use foo;$'n'-- mysql script
```

script:

```
db=$1 
cat foo.bar.users.sql  | sed "1s/^/use $db;\\$\\n/" > tmp.txt; mv tmp.txt foo.bar.users.sql
```

result

```
use foo;$n-- mysql script
```

script:

```
db=$1 
cat foo.bar.users.sql  | sed "1s/^/use $db;\$\n/" > tmp.txt; mv tmp.txt foo.bar.users.sql
```

result

```
use foo;$n-- mysql script
```

script:

```
db=$1 
cat foo.bar.users.sql  | sed "1s/^/use $db;\'$'\n/" > tmp.txt; mv tmp.txt foo.bar.users.sql
```

result:

```
use foo;'$'n-- mysql script
```

script:

```
db=$1 
cat foo.bar.users.sql  | sed "1s/^/use $db;\\\n/" > tmp.txt; mv tmp.txt foo.bar.users.sql
```

result:

```
use foo;\n-- mysql script
```

script:

```
db=$1 
cat foo.bar.users.sql  | sed "1s/^/use $db;\\n/" > tmp.txt; mv tmp.txt foo.bar.users.sql
```

result:

```
use foo;n-- mysql script
```

script:

```
db=$1 
cr="\n"
cat foo.bar.users.sql  | sed "1s/^/use $db;${cr}/" > tmp.txt; mv tmp.txt foo.bar.users.sql
```

result:

```
use foo;n-- mysql script
```

script:

```
db=$1 
cr="
"
cat foo.bar.users.sql  | sed "1s/^/use $db;${cr}/" > tmp.txt; mv tmp.txt foo.bar.users.sql
```

result:

```
use foo;^M-- mysql script
```

script:

```
db=$1 
cr="$'\n'"
cat foo.bar.users.sql  | sed "1s/^/use $db;${cr}/" > tmp.txt; mv tmp.txt foo.bar.users.sql
```

result:

```
use foo;$'n'-- mysql script
```

script:

```
db=$1 
cr="\n"
cat foo.bar.users.sql  | sed "1s/^/use $db;\\${cr}/" > tmp.txt; mv tmp.txt foo.bar.users.sql
```

result:

```
use foo;\n-- mysql script
```

Any clues welcomed

Comment: I believe BSD (and by extension usually OSX) does not support \n as a representation of a newline (it turns it into \n). Which, as you can see, is extremely aggravating. I believe (but haven't tried it) that you can escape a new line - so in the sed quoted part do a \ and then hit return. Yes, it can be difficult. I use gawk :-)

Comment: Bash supports [ANSI C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) which means you can do this: `nl=$'\n'` in the script. I believe what you did with `cr="<return>"` is POSIX but when I looked it up, the example used single quotes. Getting ^M made me laugh out loud, sorry...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed` is great for editing within lines, but bad at working with line ends. If you must use `sed`, you could insert an unused character (like "§") and `tr`ansform it into a CR later:

```
db=$1 
cat foo.bar.users.sql | sed "1s/^/use $db;\\§/" | tr "§" "\n" > tmp.txt; mv tmp.txt foo.bar.users.sql
```

but the easiest way might be to combine the output of `echo` and `cat` in order to create the prefix line:

```
db=$1 
(
    echo "use $db;"
    cat foo.bar.users.sql
) > tmp.txt; mv tmp.txt foo.bar.users.sql
```

Comment: OMG, that tr hack is horrible. I love it!

Comment: You're right I was fixated on using sed.  love this answer, thanks!

Comment: @slashdottir I admire your systematic approach with `sed` though; did the same thing at the time :)